# Convert 1 column for each dataframe in list

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I needed to split a dataframe by rows earlier, and now I have a huge list of 65 dataframes.

```
df_list = split(df, list(df$group))
new_col_name = c("A", "B","group")
df_list = lapply(df_list, setNames, nm=new_col_name)
df_list = lapply(df_list, function(x) x[-1,])
```

I want to convert column A (across all dataframes in the list) to factor instead of numeric.

```
>head(df_list)

$`0`
        A          B    count
.3375E+03  .5295E+00        0
.3380E+03  .4412E+00        0
.3385E+03  .0123E+00        0

$`1`
       A           B    count
.3370E+03  .4939E+00        1
.3375E+03  .5295E+00        1
.3380E+03  .5679E+00        1

$`2
       A           B    count
.3370E+03  .4934E+00        2
.3375E+03  .5286E+00        2
.3380E+03  .5673E+00        2
```

Etc.

Here's some reproducible data (I've converted the first variable to a factor for simplicity).

```
test = data.frame(A = c(".3375E+03", ".3380E+03", ".3385E+03"),
B = c(.5295E+00 , .4412E+00, .0123E+00),
C = c(0,0,0))
```

I have tried the following:

```
for (i in df_list){ 
  i$A = as.numeric(as.character(i$A))
}
```

But somehow this doesn't actually get assigned to df_list:

```
> str(df_list[[1]])
'data.frame':   549 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A       : Factor w/ 551 levels ".3370E+03",".3375E+03",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
```

There is probably a way to do it with `apply()` or `sapply()` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369333/convert-factors-in-2-data-frames-of-a-list-into-numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `for(i in ...)`, each `i` is a copy of an element. You're only assigning to the copy, which doesn't affect the original. To reference specific objects, you're best off using names or indices. So the way to get your code working is:

```
for (i in seq_along(df_list)) { 
  df_list[[i]]$A = as.numeric(as.character(df_list[[i]]$A))
}
```